# Cannot Import LinearRegression from Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

gives me this error in Jupyter Notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-36ba82e2d702> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
      2 
      3 lin_reg = LinearRegression()
      4 lin_reg.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)

C:\Users\David\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py in <module>()
     19                                  MultiTaskElasticNet, MultiTaskElasticNetCV,
     20                                  MultiTaskLassoCV)
---> 21 from .huber import HuberRegressor
     22 from .sgd_fast import Hinge, Log, ModifiedHuber, SquaredLoss, Huber
     23 from .stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier, SGDRegressor

C:\Users\David\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\huber.py in <module>()
     10 from ..utils import check_X_y
     11 from ..utils import check_consistent_length
---> 12 from ..utils import axis0_safe_slice
     13 from ..utils.extmath import safe_sparse_dot
     14 

ImportError: cannot import name axis0_safe_slice
```

I can import things from sklearn.preprocessing fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Don't know what the exact issue was, but uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn fixed this for me:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn
```